# Django inconsistent queryset results

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, psql

I'm noticing some inconsistency after some bulk additions were made to the dataset. Beforehand, the IDs from Metadata always returned querysets. Now, half of the IDs in Metadata are returning a queryset, while the new batch are always returning empty querysets.

models.py:

```py
class Metadata(models.Model):
  strain_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

psql:
(note single quotes added around IDs 2290 and 1002, not present in Django .query statements)

```sh
## Old batch:
pg=# SELECT DISTINCT ON (U0."strain_id") U0."id" FROM "chat_metadata" U0 WHERE U0."strain_id" IN ('2290') ORDER BY U0."strain_id" ASC;
  id  
------
 1457
(1 row)

## New batch (working here???):
pg=# SELECT DISTINCT ON (U0."strain_id") U0."id" FROM "chat_metadata" U0 WHERE U0."strain_id" IN ('1002') ORDER BY U0."strain_id" ASC;
  id  
------
 1474
(1 row)
```

However, the result of `.queryset.query` is `SELECT DISTINCT ON (U0."strain_id") U0."id" FROM "chat_metadata" U0 WHERE U0."strain_id" IN (2290) ORDER BY U0."strain_id" ASC`. This magically works when run inside Django and returns a valid queryset. However, when run from psql, the following occurs:

```sh
pg=# SELECT DISTINCT ON (U0."strain_id") U0."id" FROM "chat_metadata" U0 WHERE U0."strain_id" IN (2290) ORDER BY U0."strain_id" ASC;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ..."id" FROM "chat_metadata" U0 WHERE U0."strain_id" IN (2290) ...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

This is a little distressing as the old batch (2290) is showing in Django whereas the new batch (1002) returns an empty queryset. Perhaps reset_db would help clear the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the database appears to do the trick:

```sh
$./manage.py flush
```